# ios play continues sound when app receive push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Currently i am working on app in which i want to play continues sound when app receives push notification. as i know apple allow to play custom sound of length  of 30 sec here is [link..](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6)

but in well known app it plays continues sound in driver side when app is in back ground and driver receives order.

and another issue is of when my app is in back ground and receives push notification Rather clicking on notification if i open app by pressing app icon it does not show me data of push. it is not possible to load data when press on app icon here is link

[iOS Push notification issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076380/ios-push-notification-issue)

but same thing is done in well known app

Comment: I want to implement that two functionality in my app..

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 7+, use `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`, which is called even if your app is in the background. iOS will even launch your app in the background if it's not already running, but if the user force quits the app, it will not be re-launched. If you enable the `remote-notification` background mode, you can run app code when the notification arrives. If you include the `audio` background mode, you could initiate a sound that continues to play while app is in background.

For second question, typically, your app should query a server for updates if it's launched directly. However, you could leverage a remote notification as above, which you'd get in most cases (except if the app were force quit).

Comment: i Have implemented application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:  but does not call when app is open using app icon and there is already push notification.it directly call applicationDidBecomeActive method  ..

Comment: No, nothing is delivered when you open the app using the app icon, but if you are using `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`, you should have already received and processed the notification unless the app was forced quit. If that doesn't suit your needs, then do standard approach, which is query the server.

Comment: do you have a sample code/demo for handling push when app is in back ground in which application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: method is called?? i will cross check it with my code. because i can't go with query server approach.